# Rails - Use ENV variable in yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

This is `myfile.yml`

```
this_is_key:
  - [<%= ENV['MY_KEY_NAME'] %>, 1]
```

It will return the error syntax, can not parse file.Now, i change like this:

```
this_is_key:
  - [my_key_here, 1]
```

No errors occurred. Somebody can tell me, how can i pass ENV variable in my file?

Comment: What is your desired result

Comment: @Toàn
Did you tried https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro gem?

Comment: That is not a valid YAML file. You cannot have an `[`' in the middle of an unquoted scalar.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it only if you parse the resulting `yml` file as an `erb` template:

```
YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("myfile.yml")).result)
```

`result` method passes the current `binding` into template and renders the file according to the variables in the scope.

Here's an [article](http://urgetopunt.com/2009/09/12/yaml-config-with-erb.html) about such experiments.

Answer (score 0):

works by renaming .yml to .yml.erb in my case.